# How do I specify IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY for all urls except LoginController Grails spring security Request map?

Tags: grails, spring-security

We are using spring security request map table in grails. How to specify `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` for all urls **except** `LoginController` in database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume you haven't already read the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/requestMappings.html#requestmapInstances) as it explains how to do this. Typically you will want to allow access to more than just the "login" controller as well. I will include that here so that you don't run into problems with other resources not being available.

The documentation shows you a snippet of code that sets up the basic security when using "`Requestmap`" (e.g. Database). Typically this code will be run in `Bootstrap.groovy`. Let's get that out of the way first.

```
for (String url in [
      '/', '/index', '/index.gsp', '/**/favicon.ico',
      '/**/js/**', '/**/css/**', '/**/images/**',
      '/login', '/login.*', '/login/*',
      '/logout', '/logout.*', '/logout/*']) {
   new Requestmap(url: url, configAttribute: 'permitAll').save()
}
```

The above code will allow full access to the listed resources.

Now, moving on to your specific question. The pattern `/**` will match everything not already defined above. You also stated you want it to require `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` so it will look something like this:

```
new Requestmap(url: '/**', configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY').save()
```

Keep in mind that order of these rules is important. Spring security will pick the first matching rule and apply it.

Comment: @Moore
Thank you for your detailed explanation.

Comment: Why do you prefer requestmap, stored in database? `grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap` looks like more flexible solution

Comment: @baxxabit They are both equally capable. I personally use interceptUrlMap since security in my applications doesn't change all that much. However, some applications require the ability to change the security settings at run-time and through a UI. In that case the database based requestmap is much more flexible.